# Traveling UK-Russia-UK

Tags: uk-residents, russian-citizens

My daughter has lived in UK for 4 years. She is a Russian citizen and has a Residence Permit in UK, type: "**Dependant**. Leave to remain" (her mother married a UK citizen). The residence permit is valid until 05-2024. She is 18 years old (i.e. she is an **Adult**.)

In 06-2023 she is going to visit Russia (flight through an another country) and will come back to the UK in 07-2023. Are there any risks of problems with crossing the border on the way back to UK? Can there be problems with obtaining citizenship in the future? Thank you!

Comment: Is she still living with you and financially dependent on you?

Comment: It seems there are really two questions here, 1. Will a trip to russia cause any problems for her status in the UK, and 2. Will the Russians let her leave.

Answer (score 5):

An application for citizenship would require your daughter to have lived in the UK for 5 years and to have had one of the following for 12 months:

- indefinite leave to remain in the UK
- ‘settled status’ (also known as  - -  - ‘indefinite leave to remain under the EU Settlement Scheme’)
- indefinite leave to enter the UK (permission to move to the UK permanently from abroad)

https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-indefinite-leave-to-remain

Since your daughter does not yet have ILR, the restrictions on that status relating to time spent outside the UK do not apply.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Please give a comment about this matter: is there any proplem if my daughter will cross back UK board as Adult who has DEPENDANT LTR?

Comment: @Mikhail I don’t see why it would be a problem. Her visa will still be valid, UKVI would have known her date of birth when she applied.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a issue here, the permit is valid on return and there aren't any restrictions in place that would prevent visiting Russia as a BRP Holder